# ASP.NET App_Themes with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, app-themes

I have a ASP.NET web forms project that has css, images, and skins in an App_Themes folder. We would like to integrate Boostrap into the project without loosing the look and feel defined by App_Themes. Does anyone know how best to integrate Bootstrap into ASP.NET WebForms project using App_Themes?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Bootstrap (4) is to implement my own sass file that overrides the bootstrap sass variables The out of the box bootstrap.sass file just references all the boostrap mixin, utilities and component files and has no contents of its own, so you can either make a copy of the bootstrap file or modify it yourself.  Copying it and tweaking it to reference additional files of your own, such as variable overrides, etc, is easy and allows you to incorporate future bootstrap update easily without losing your own changes.

So you could put the bootsrap files anywhere you want, and in the app_themes\theme directory create your own sass file that is a copy of the boostrap file, then reference the resulting .css file from your application.    The caviate is that you will need to refactor your css to be sass, that leverages the boostrap framework.